# How can i measure the time between when i send request and when i get responce by using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I use `enterHttpWebRequest` for sending request to a `URL` and got the response from that

```
WebResponse response = HttpWebRequest.Create(_url3).GetResponse();
```

I want to measure  time between when i send request and when i get responce, is there any way?

Comment: You can use Stopwatch in the System.Diagnostics namespace for that